# What is the easiest way to visualize transactional data utilizing using a data dump like MySQL, CSV etc etc

Tags: mysql, database, mapping, reporting

Essentially I want to be able to feed it data and see fancy charts and graphs displaying information out of the data based on x amount of transactions etc etc and/or SQL statements etc.

It does not matter if it is client based or web based. Open source would be great but commercial is fine also.

Comment: What's with the down vote have you got fanboys?

Comment: Not that I know off. Oh well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [myDBR](http://mydbr.com). It allows you to easily generate reports and also takes care of the report layout.

To make a report you just write a stored procedure (either with the included SQL editor or with your preferred DB tool). The data generated by the stored procedure is then interpreted by myDBR. For example to create a chart of your monthly sales you would write the following code:

```
select 'dbr.chart', 'Column', '2D Column';
select Name, SUM(Items)
FROM demo.TestTable
GROUP BY Name;
```

There are plenty of chart types and configuration options available.

myDBR community version is free of charge, and the premium version is only 129 EUR / year.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a job for Google!  Well here's some info anyway :)

[Crystal Reports](http://www.crystalreports.com/) is one of the most popular commercial systems for more of a reporting server.

Microsoft Excell can be used to create reports out of your csv data.  You'll have to create the excell sheets yourself and dump the data.  It can be automated with VBScript or .NET.

Also look into bluya for a free solution but I don't really know much about it.

Oh and .NET has the sql report thing for free.  It's built in as a asp.net control so you can see it in the visual studio toolbox.